# Python on windows: gtk import error.

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I'm having fun with python, and would like to learn gui programming.

I installed pygtk, and gtk but I get this message when I try to import gtk:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import gtk
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gtk-2.0\gtk\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from gtk import _gtk
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

First I tried downloading and installing from several different sources. That didn't work, now I have Gtk+ and GTK2 Runtime folders in my program files.

I take it that these are different versions of GTK runtime?
Next I googled this, and found suggestions to make sure GTK was in my path. I've added every combination of paths to the lib and bin folders in these two directories. Still not working.
 What should I try next?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try pygtk-all-in-one? It's available in http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.22/ It worked fine on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

PyGTK itself has several dependencies (cairo et al), did you install all of them?